# How can I separate the slice?

Tags: boolean-modifier

I want to separate the slice_low from the 5_low.

Is there a way to avoid it? It was sliced with Boxcuuter.

[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by separate? Slice_low seems to be the child of 5_low, to unparent, select the object in the 3D view and Alt P > Unparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like boxcutter has automatically parented slice object to original object. To unparent the objects you can use Blender's builtin operator called *Clear and Keep Transformation*. This operator can be found by pressing *Alt + P*.

Alternatively you can go to *Object* menu that is located on the *Header* of the *3D Viewport* then *Parent -> Clear and Keep Transformation*.

If you are for some reason interested in scripted approach, here is the example of the code you can use to clear parent and keep transformation:

```py
import bpy

# Defining original and slice objects
original_object = bpy.data.objects['5_low']
slice_object    = bpy.data.objects['Slice_low']

slice_location = slice_object.matrix_world.to_translation() # Storing original location of slice_object
slice_object.parent = None # Clearing slice_object's parent
slice_object.matrix_world.translation = slice_location # Setting unparented slice_object's location to the intial location
```

Documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/editing/parenting.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh sad, iam feeling like a noob now. But Thanks a lot, didnt thought it can be a parented Object. Helped me alot and worked easily.